# Resources for Computational Algebra

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, online-resources

I am a graduate student in computer science.

I am intersted in Algebra and computation (mostly in group theoretic ) or also named as computational Algebra. What are the best resources for this topic other than lecture notes given by [Madhu Sudan MIT](http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/ST12/) . As I am a student of computer I am looking for resources that also focus on computational challenges.

Comment: Try the group theory package GAP.

Comment: @ Wuestenfux Thanks